# MySQL: Join three tables and concatenate grouped results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have following three tables 'doctors' ,'specialities' and 'doctor_specialities':

```
doctors 
-id
-doctor_name

specialities 
-id
-speciality_name

doctor_specialities 
-id
-doctor_id
-speciality_id
```

I'd like to return all doctors along with their speciality name and speciality id. A doctor can have multiple specialities.

The result-set should look something like:

```
id       |       doctor_name       |       speciality_id       |       speciality_name
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        |       John              |       5,3                 |       Speciality1,Speciality2
3        |       Tim               |       3                   |       Speciality2
6        |       David             |       NULL                |       NULL
```

I tried below query:

```
SELECT d.id ,d.doctor_name, s.speciality_name, s.id
AS speciality_id
FROM api_doctors d
LEFT JOIN api_doctor_specialities ds
ON ds.doctor_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN api_specialities s
ON s.id = ds.speciality_id
GROUP BY d.id
```

but in this case I am getting single speciality.

Comment: 1 select, with 2 joins

Comment: If i didn't know any better I would say this is homework.

Comment: I would hope anyone teaching this wouldn't be teaching people to set up tables this way.

Comment: i think the db table structure looks appropriate @DarylB, what do you think the problem with it is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is a MySQL function called [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat), which returns either a concatenated result or NULL. The default separator is a comma, so the results from this query should match your desired result-set.

```
SELECT d.id, d.doctor_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.speciality_name) AS speciality_name, GROUP_CONCAT(s.id) AS speciality_id
FROM api_doctors d
LEFT JOIN api_doctor_specialities ds
ON ds.doctor_id = d.id
LEFT JOIN api_specialities s
ON s.id = ds.speciality_id
GROUP BY d.id
```

Schema and query on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be4680/19/0)